# lubuntu bootloader does not work properly

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu, system-installation

I am trying to install lubuntu on my older laptop. I have created a bootable CD and the install seems to go fine, but after I am prompted to remove the boot disk and restart, the computer boots straight to windows.

I have tried Boot-Repair to no avail. The url Boot-Repair puts out is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6906712/. Inside the bootable cd, I have checked the partitions through the terminal. It seems as though there are no linux partitions. I am not sure if there is supposed to be one after a linux install (again newer linux user). I am not sure whether my problem is with the install itself or simply with grub.

How can I fix or debug this?

Comment: You sure the installation starts at all? I can't even see that you have installed... anything.

Answer (score 0):

Windows appears to be taking up the whole disk. You need to partition the disk with the partition manager on the install disk to create room for the Lubuntu install. Alternatively you could shrink the Windows partition from within Windows to create empty space for the install.